# container-fluid and side padding with Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I want my page's content to take up the full width of the screen with a little padding on the right and left and be fluid, but when I wrap my `div.row` and `div.col-md-x` in a `<div class="container-fluid">` the page's content touches the sides of the screen.

```
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
```

What is the proper, Bootstrap way to have a `100% width`, fluid layout, and 15px padding on the left and right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container):

```
Use .container-fluid for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport.
```

If you want 15px padding then add to your CSS:

```
.container-fluid {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

However you may want to use a percent (`padding: 2%`) or media queries since `15px` will look different on different screen resolutions.

Another option: use `<div class="container">`  instead of `<div class="container-fluid">`.  This will give you built in padding.

#### [Bootply demo](http://www.bootply.com/Z6GHlwiMg3)

Comment: div.container puts the page's content in a centered, 1170px width div with lots of extra space on either side

Comment: Bootstrap does so many common things for you, and this seems like such a common thing, I am slightly stunned that you have to modify its CSS to achieve this and there's no pre-defined class or whatever.

Comment: I guess they give you the `container` as a built in option with padding, or otherwise you have to define it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can try an id to `<div id="bd" class="container-fluid">` and if add this script after add Jquery you can padding when window resize, and can add more resolutions px with more "if" or only add padding-left or right.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    function paddingbd(){
      if($(window).width()>800){
        $("#bd").css("padding","30px");
      }else{
        $("#bd").css("padding","");
      }
    }

    paddingbd();

    $(window).on("resize",paddingbd);

  });
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `.row` has a negative margin of `15px`. try to add

```
.container-fluid {
    padding: 15px 30px;
}
```