# Bootstrap navbar 100% width not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On my bootstrap nav bar I am trying to make to go to the full with on page even when nav bar is on top of image.

But I have tried width 100% on `.navbar-wrapper` and `navbar` and `navbar-default` But for some reason the navbar will still not go full width of page.

Live Examples

Here is my codepen [Code View](http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/gpWrZK)

Here is my codepen [Full View](http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/full/gpWrZK/)

**Question** How can I make my navbar width 100% work so it goes to the full width of page?

**CSS**

```
/* Special class on .container surrounding .navbar, used for positioning it into place. */
.navbar-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 20;
}

/* Flip around the padding for proper display in narrow viewports */
.navbar-wrapper > .container {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    width: 100% !important;
}

.navbar-inverse {
  width: 100% !important;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
}

.navbar-inverse .nav > li > a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-inverse .nav > li > a:hover {
    background: none;
}

.navbar-brand a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.main-header-background {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
    background-image: url('./images/stars/img-stars-2.jpg');
    height: 620px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
<div class="container">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<div class="navbar-brand">
<a href="#">Brand</a>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>

</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
</div>
</div>

<div class="main-header-background">
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJmqdL

Comment: @KhanhTO It worked what I was after. Can you please make it as a answer and explain what you did.

Comment: It should be similar with the below answers, changing to `container-fluid`, and setting 0 to padding left and right: `.navbar-wrapper > .container-fluid {
   padding-right: 0;
   padding-left: 0;
}`. I'm not sure if I should post as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get the width of the navbar to go the full length of the page by making the container inherit from ".navbar-wrapper". You may also want to get rid of the padding you have set in ".navbar-wrapper .navbar"

The following styles worked for me: 
See codpen: http://codepen.io/JordanLittell/pen/wadWxv

/* Special class on .container surrounding .navbar, used for positioning it into place. */

```
.navbar-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 20;
}

/* Flip around the padding for proper display in narrow viewports */
.navbar-wrapper > .container {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    width: inherit;
}

.navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    width: 100% !important;
}

.navbar-inverse {
  width: 100% !important;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-inverse .nav > li > a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-inverse .nav > li > a:hover {
    background: none;
}

.navbar-brand a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.main-header-background {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
    background-image: url('http://www.riwakawebsitedesigns.com/external/images/stars/img-stars-2.jpg');
  height: 620px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Seems you are using `.container` class instead of `container-fluid` class. As per bootstrap documentation:

> Turn any fixed-width grid layout into a full-width layout by changing
>   your outermost `.container` to `.container-fluid`.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-fluid

updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpWMzJ

Comment: I'm using `.container-fluid` but still navbar has some space on right and left

Comment: Dear @InzimamTariqIT The container-fluid class has some side padding by default so perhaps that’s what you mean? If so, maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344168/container-fluid-and-side-padding-with-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 3):

You should use the class `container-fluid` instead of `container`.

- `container` has predefined width values for the different screen sizes (xs, sm, md, lg)
- `container-fluid` fills the available width

Also `container`'s have some padding applied, and generally they are used in conjunction with `row`'s that have the inverse margin.

So if you want **full-width** you either have to wrap your navbar in a row (inside your container) or you just don't use `container`'s at all.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old one, but still relevant now, especially with the world of modern CSS frameworks!

I had my "*row*" class on the nav, because inside the nav I wanted to control elements with Bootstrap's grid system.

So it looked something like:

```html
<nav class="navbar row"></nav>
```

What I needed to do was remove row from the nav itself and place it inside the the div. So it changed to:

```html
<nav class="navbar> <div class="row"> </div> </nav>
```

It seemed to be a problem with Bootstrap's grid system itself. Hope this helps anyone out there!